# Doxygen C# XML comments: multiply enum's with same name and different scope got merged?

Tags: c#, documentation, doxygen

I have very strange problem with Doxygen: I used it to create documentation from XML tags of my C# code as suggested in some other StackOverflow question. Basically heres the situation:

```
//file: Foo1
public class Foo1
{
    public enum Bar
    {
        Bar1,
        Bar2
    }
}
//file: Foo2
public class Foo2
{
    public enum Bar
    {
        Bar3,
        Bar4
    }
}
```

And in final docs generated by Doxygen I have:

```
Foo1 Class Reference
(...)
Public Types
enum    Bar{
  Bar1, Bar2, Bar3, Bar4
}
```

And:

```
Foo2 Class Reference
(...)
Public Types
enum    Bar{
  Bar1, Bar2, Bar3, Bar4
}
```

I do not know if it is a bug, or I have done something wrong with Doxygen configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in Doxygen 1.5.5-1.5.9 that is claimed to have been fixed in Doxygen 1.6.0.

The [history of the bug](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=522193) links back to this very question.